# {"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js Error compiling template:

Tags: vue.js

I get the bellow error when I run my vue project:

```
./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-003cf1bf","hasScoped":true,"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./node_modules/iview-loader??ref--0-1!./src/components/common/path-nav.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  <div class="path-nav">
    <i-breadcrumb>
      <i-breadcrumb-item v-for="route in route_list" to="{{route.route}}">{{ route.name }}</i-breadcrumb-item>
    </i-breadcrumb>
  </div>
```

---

my key code is bellow:

```
<template>
  <div class="path-nav">
    <i-breadcrumb>
      <i-breadcrumb-item v-for="route in route_list" to="{{route.route}}">{{ route.name }}</i-breadcrumb-item>
    </i-breadcrumb>
  </div>
</template>
```

If I comment the:

```
<i-breadcrumb-item v-for="route in route_list" to="{{route.route}}">{{ route.name }}</i-breadcrumb-item>
```

There I will not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
to="{{route.route}}"
```

has been deprecated and removed in `Vue.js2`

you can use

```
:to="route.route"
```